# Classifying singularities of an entire function at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

In preparing for an examination, I have run across the following problem that has me stumped:

Let $f$ be an entire function, where $f(0)=\alpha, \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, and for all $z\in\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\},\ |f(z)f(1/z)|\leq 1$. Classify the singularities at $z=\infty$ of $f$ for all values of $\alpha$.

In taking limits, I believe that it is clear that if $\alpha\neq 0$, $f$ has an removable singularity at $z=\infty$. However, I am having trouble seeing what happens if $\alpha=0$.

I know that if $f$ is entire, $f$ is a polynomial if and only if $f$ has a pole at $z=\infty$. Also, I have attempted using Schwarz's Lemma, but was not able to come to a conclusion as to whether $f$ has a pole or an essential singularity at $\infty$.

What would be the proper path to classify the infinite singularities given a polynomial with no constant term?

In advance, thank you for any help provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant bit of technique here is to factor out the zero when $\alpha = 0$. Note in the case where $\alpha \neq 0$, $f$ is an entire function with a removable singularity at $\infty$, and hence is a constant.

For $\alpha = 0$, provided that $f$ is not uniformly $0$, then $f(z) = z^k h(z)$ where $h(0) \neq 0$ is entire. Then for any $z \in \mathbb{C} - 0$, $$|h(z) h(1/z)| = \left| h(z) z^k h(1/z) (1/z)^k \right| = |f(z) f(1/z)| \leq 1.$$

So by previous analysis, $h(z)$ is an entire function satisfying our condition with $h(0) \neq 0$, and hence must in fact be a constant. So $f(z) = c z^k$ for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$, and in particular $f(z)$ has a pole at $\infty$ or is the $0$ function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response! This clears things up tremendously